# how to check a mutex exists for a scheduled job using laravel tinker?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, cron, tinker

I have a job scheduled to run every hour. 'withoutOverlapping' is set for this job and mutex expiry time is 24 hour.

But when I checked cron.log. I found that it is not running every hour. But it runs once in a day and at the end of job, there is a redis write error. I think this error is getting when clearing mutex (lock) of this job from redis after completion of job execution.  Then after 24 hour, mutex expires automatically, then this job runs next hour.

To check mutex clears from redis or not, I need to see mutex of this job exists. So I tried below cod in tinker but it is showing zero events. Actually there are 7 jobs scheduked

```
>>> $s = new Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule();
=> Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule {#3543}
>>> count($s->events())
=> 0
>>>
```

So using tinker how can I achieve this ?

Comment: Wouldnt going into redis-cli with the following command redis-cli and running "KEYS *" to find the key and see if its there?

Comment: I dont know how to get keys

Comment: run redis-cli and in the cli do KEYS *

Comment: you may need to quote it e.g. `KEYS '*'`